# How to run a command after entire build is done in AOSP?

Tags: android, makefile, build, android-source, ninja

Specifically, I'd like to tar up the root directory (e.g., out/target/product/zcu102/root), but I'd like it to automatically have it done when I build.  So for example, right now I run:

```
m -j32 && sh -c "cd out/target/product/zcu102/; tar czf root.tar.gz root"
```

But I'd like the taring process to always happen by the build itself.  Any way to do this, without modifying core Android repositories?

Comment: Why both 'makefile' and 'ninja' tags specified? Ninja uses 'build.ninja' input file with a different syntax, not 'makefile'.

Comment: AOSP uses ninja and make for building.  If I want to run a command at the very end, I don't know where it should end up going (in ninja files, make files, or other files).

Comment: That's not relevant where it will end up going, as long as you don't intend to modify the sources. But what's wrong with a simple shell script containing just the command above?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the Android build commands, not a wrapper around them with my own scripts.  Also, I have more complicated things I'd like to do than just the taring up from above...

Comment: You can write your own Makefile which invokes an existing one (cf. "recursive make") and adds some post-processing. However, I don't see which way it's better than a shell script - basically, wrapper makefile vs. wrapper shell script.